# What's the idiomatic way to build a HashMap from a Set of keys (all of which have the same value)

Tags: java, collections, initialization

I have a `Set<T> keys`, and an `Integer N`.

I would like to build a `HashMap<T, Integer> H`; where the key set of `H` is the contents of `keys`, and every value is `N`.

What is the most idiomatic way to write this in Java 7 or 8?

I'm looking for a concise syntactic equivalent of Perl's

```
my %H = map { ( $_ => $N ) } @keys; # Map instead of loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = 
    set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), key -> n));
```

Comment: The problem is likely in how I phrased a question, but wouldn't this produce a map where every value is the same exact object?

Comment: @DVK: yes, so what?  That's perfectly fine, if the values are immutable -- which `Integer`s are.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I stand corrected, thanks! It would be an issue if I used a different object; but mine are indeed immutable.

Comment: @DVK if you used `key -> new Integer(n)`, you would get a different instance for each key. The function is called for each key (don't do that with Integer: it's useless).

Comment: @DVK, you _asked_ for a way to set every entry to "the same value", then you worried that the technique would produce entries with the same value. Color me puzzled.

Comment: @LewBloch - my bad for using imprecise terminology. "same value" was not meant to be "same object" but "object with same content" - for lack of a better word, cloned value.